# Wordpress advance carousel manipulate by JS for autoplay doesnt work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I am using JS inserted in HTML widget into wordpress page to manipulate advanced carousel widget served by royal elementor addon free version. However, because the autoplay function can only be utilise in pro version i tried to use JS to trigger click events on the nav button inside the carousel. it looks like it did click, but it doesnt seems to be click all the way.

The process is fairly simple:

- Page fully loaded, first trigger click on a toggle button to display the first hidden element.
- Inside the element there is the advanced carousel with navigation button.
- After the initial clicks, the code supposed to click on nav button to simulate autoplay function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fadeDuration = 1000;
    var initialClick = true;

    // Button click handler
    $('.toggle-button').on('click', function() {
        if (initialClick) {
            var $rightNavBar = $('.toggle-content:first').find('.wpr-slider-arrow-container').find('.wpr-slider-next-arrow');
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                $rightNavBar.click();
            }
            
            // Hide all elements and fade in the corresponding one
            $('.toggle-content').hide();
            var index = $('.toggle-button').index(this);
            $('.toggle-content').eq(index).fadeIn(fadeDuration);
            
            initialClick = false;
        } else {
            $('.toggle-content').hide();
            var index = $('.toggle-button').index(this);
            $('.toggle-content').eq(index).fadeIn(fadeDuration);
        }
    });

    // Trigger a click event on the first toggle button when the page is loaded
    $('.toggle-button:first').click();
```

I am using wordpress 6.3.1, elementor 3.16.4 and royal elementor addon 1.3.77

What happened instead:

- Page fully loaded and the first trigger did display the first hidden element.
- But the carousel doesnt seems to work properly.
- Sometimes it did click on the nav button. most of the time it doesnt.

Answer (score -2):

Please elaborate more on your situation. From what i gather, what you trying to do look similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var fadeDuration = 1000;
var initialClick = true;
var isIterating = true;

function handleButtonClick() {
    if (isIterating) {
        isIterating = false;
    }

    $('.toggle-content').hide();
    var index = $('.toggle-button').index(this);
    $('.toggle-content').eq(index).fadeIn(fadeDuration);

    initialClick = false;
}

$('toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    if (initialClick) {
        handleButtonClick.call(this);
    } else {
        handleButtonClick.call(this);
    }
});

var toggleButtons = $('.toggle-button');
var currentButtonIndex = 0;

function clickNextButton() {
    if (isIterating && currentButtonIndex < toggleButtons.length) {
        toggleButtons.eq(currentButtonIndex).click();
        currentButtonIndex++;
        setTimeout(clickNextButton, 1000);
    }
}

clickNextButton();

$('toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    if (isIterating) {
        isIterating = false
    }
})
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior and revise your opening for your answer. Belittling / mocking (new) members questions is inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I have revised my opening.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).